# Full-width Spinner in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I'd really like my app to have a Spinner which stretches the entire length of my ActionBar, like the one in Gmail 4.0. Anyone know how to achieve this? Even if I set "match_parent" in the Spinner layout resource, it doesn't fill the entire bar. Preferably, I'd like to be able to have it fill the entire bar except for my action items, rather than using the split actionbar as well.

**EDIT**: see my answer below for an implementation using the built-in actionbar, or hankystyles' when using a custom view

[image]

Comment: How about paddings - does the image resource for the button itself include a bit of padding?

Comment: Do you have multiple accounts set up? Mine also spans all the way to the right like yours do, but I think that's mainly because I have several accounts set up. The content of the 'drop down' (or what it's called) is then different - and wider.

Comment: yeah, I've got 2 accounts set up. It's kinda of strange to have it different depending on how many accounts you have!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Bit annoying that I've just done it, but here is a method of doing it using the built-in Spinner in the action bar. All you need to do is make your spinner item's main container a `RelativeLayout` and set its gravity to fillHorizontal, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-4dip"
    android:text="@string/gen_placeholder"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@android:id/text1"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And initialising the Adapter as so:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> barAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, R.layout.subtitled_spinner_item, 
    android.R.id.text1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.actionList));
barAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

which then gives the required spinner spanning the entire actionbar (except for the action buttons):

[image: Spanned actionbar]

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by setting the spinner item's "main container"?  Any chance you could give an example of how you added the above layout?

Comment: I mean the enclosing layout of your spinner item. The xml code above generates the full-width spinner as shown.

Comment: So do you need a custom adapter to go with this?

Comment: Nope! I just used an `ArrayAdapter`, then passed the xml resource as shown above to the `setDropDownResource(..)` method.

Comment: Ok :) I think Im close.. Here's the code Im using:

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.locations,
                R.layout.actionbar_main);

R.layout.actionbar_main contains the xml above.  The problem is I need to 
somehow pull out the id of the textview to pass to the adapter.  Do you need to
inflate it?  Thanks for the help..

Comment: I've added the code used to initialise my adapter, I didn't use `createFromResource(..)` because I don't think it's as flexible. subtitled_spinner_item is the xml layout in the post.

Comment: This works really nice. However, I'm trying to get the View for the selected item (I need to modify the static part of the text). I've tried barAdapter.getView() but this just got me a new View, not the one that is selected so modifying it didn't change anything.

Comment: @ Espiandev - Any way to do this without losing the action bar title and subtitle?  Once I set the textview width to match_parent the title of the activity gets cut off.  I'm actually NOT using any action items, i'd just like to have the home icon, title, and spinner.

Comment: I think on phones its designed so that you only see the spinner or the title, not both. Might be worth having the spinner show the title at all times, like how in the example above the second text view only shows "Formulae" - nothing else.

Comment: ...that's exactly what my boss just suggested....thanks for your reply and this post!  Helped me out a lot!

Comment: @Espiandev how do you add those 3 dots at right side of the ActionBar ?

Comment: @Espiandev > is there a way to have the **selected** item content (In this case the first item text : "Chemistry") **WRAPPED** in the spinner ? Like for Google Maps Actionbar spinner items for example.

Comment: I think not using a RelativeLayout and setting everything's width to wrap_content should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's helped me in several ways.  However, if I use match_parent on all items it pushes the other action icons off the screen.  How did you keep your overflow and search button as shown?

Comment: Is it possible to customize the spinner, and also get the spinner view itself to make operations on it programmatically ?

Comment: How did you add the spinner to the action bar? @AlexCurran

Answer (score 20):

The spinner on my gmail app also spans the entire width of my action bar.  This solution worked for me:

```
View spinner = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar_spinner, null);
actionBar.setCustomView(spinner);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

Where the spinner layout is like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="fill_horizontal" >
    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/spinner_text"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I suspect there's a better solution to be had by overriding the default action bar navigation style [like this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html) but I couldn't immediately get that working.

Comment: ah brilliant, thanks. I'd prefer an implementation which uses the standard navigation controls (i.e. not a custom view), but if no-one give me one by the end, I'll award the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the background of the spinner to an image file.  The default background has caused me layout issues, but when I set it to my own png of a blank 1x1 pixle it filled my layout as I wanted.  If that works you may have to create a custom image that works for you.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a TextView inside your Spinner, you can set the minEms to a high value. This is the easiest workaround I explored:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spinner_active"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="blaa"
        android:minEms="100"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```