# Is it possible to use sliding tabs and a spinner in the action bar in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, spinner, android-tabs

I currently have an Activity with sliding tabs on it and I have been using ActionBarSherlock, but I wanted to have a spinner in the action bar, so that the user could select items from the spinner and each item is a specific file which opens up values to re-populate the views on each tab. I have looked to see how you can do this and so far have not had any luck. I don't want them to both navigate through fragments, but instead have the spinner to re-populate views on the tabs. I looked at a similar question [Is it possible to use dropdown AND tabs as navigation in the action bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768313/is-it-possible-to-use-dropdown-and-tabs-as-navigation-in-the-action-bar) which is how I want it to look, but his question was to use two different types of navigation. Please can anyone help me and let me know if this is possible. Thank you in advance. I have also just looked at an Android application that I have which is the Eurosport app and that has the type of layout that I am looking for if anyone has that application to see what I mean.

Here is my code:

```
public class SlidingTabsActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity
{

ViewPager viewPager;
TabsAdapter tabsAdapter;
ActionBar actionBarTabs;
Spinner spinner;
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
LayoutInflater spinnerLayoutInflater;
View spinnerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    viewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    viewPager.setId(R.id.pager);
    setContentView(viewPager);

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, R.array.device_description);
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    spinnerView = spinnerLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner, null);
    spinner = (Spinner) spinnerView.findViewById(R.id.tabsSpinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });

    actionBarTabs = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBarTabs.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBarTabs.setCustomView(spinnerView);
    actionBarTabs.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBarTabs.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    tabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, viewPager); // Declares the tabs adapter class with the view pager view

    /* Adds fragments to the tabs adapter */
    tabsAdapter.addTab(actionBarTabs.newTab().setText("PV"), Fragment_1.class, null);
    tabsAdapter.addTab(actionBarTabs.newTab().setText("CONFIG"), Fragment_2.class, null);
    tabsAdapter.addTab(actionBarTabs.newTab().setText("DIAG"), Fragment_3.class, null);

}
```

Here is my Spinner code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/tabsSpinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I get this message in the logcat when pressing the Spinner:

```
11-26 12:22:44.282: W/InputEventReceiver(7217): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
11-26 12:22:44.282: W/InputMethodManagerService(525): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4216a290 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@42618330
```

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all create a markup file to place your `Spinner`, e.g:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" >
    </Spinner>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Next create a menu resource, e.g. `main_menu.xml` and put it to `res/menu` folder:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_change_content"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/spinner_layout"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/empty">
    </item>

</menu>
```

Paid your attention that we specified custom action layout for this menu item - this is a layout we have created earlier and it contains our `Spinner`. Next in your `Activity`(or `Fragment`) you must inflate this menu:
**Use this if you creating this menu in `Activity`**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    ...// init spinner, will be explained below
    return true;
}
```

**Or if you creating menu in `Fragment`:**

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.card_storage, menu);
    ...// init spinner
}
```

If you creating this menu for `Fragment` don't forget to call `setHasOptionMenu(true)` somewhere in `Fragment.onCreate()`.

Put this instead of `... // init spinner`

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_change_content); // id of our custom menu item
CustomSpinnerAdapter adapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(); // your adapter
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) item.getActionView().findViewById(R.id.spinner); 
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

I hope I didn't missed out something. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried this but it didn't work. It still doesn't display the list of items in the Spinner and also it now is overlapping the overflow menu, so that the menu isn't displaying. Is it possible to have the spinner in the action bar and have tabs below and always keep it like that even if the phone has rotated?

Comment: Let me clarify some aspects - spinner is empty or it isn't displayed? To avoid menu overlapping try to play with spinner size - in my case it was pretty small (Just one word of text) and I've got no such problems. Also if you post your code it will be simpler to understand what exactly goes on.

Comment: I have just added my code that I have so far. Please code you help me and ask me anything else that you need clarifying. The spinner displays, but it is empty and it worked before with this code, but for some reason it overlaps the overflow menu.

Comment: I just figured out why it was overlapping. I had that spinner and an extra spinner in my tabs menu file. I have fixed this now. Although my problem of it being empty is still apparent. Please let me know if you know how to fix this problem.

Comment: I have added the logcat message which displays when selecting the Spinner. Could you please look at it and see if you know what it means?

Comment: Hmm... I see no obvious mistakes in your code. LogCat output isn't informative for me. Try to fill your adapter with harcoded string array not resource just for the sake of testing.

Comment: Okay I will try that, thank you very much. I think that I have actually tried that before, but I will give it another go. Please let me know if you see anything in my code or find out anything to solve my problem. Thank you.

Comment: @JamesMeade did you solve your problem? I am also stuck on there. Waiting for your reply.. thaanks

Comment: @The_Lazy_Man I did manage to solve my problem. All you have to do is create your custom Spinner layout in XML and add that layout to the ActionBar by setting ActionBar.setCustomView().