# Spinner and ArrayAdapter NullPointerException in Android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I am not sure why I am getting a NullPointerException, but it is happening at the line `spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter)`. Could anyone please have a look at my code to see what the problem is and how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
public class SlidingTabsActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity
{

ViewPager viewPager;
TabsAdapter tabsAdapter;
ActionBar actionBarTabs;
Spinner spinner;
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

PopupFirmware popupFirmware; // Popup firmware class instance

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    viewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    viewPager.setId(R.id.pager);
    setContentView(viewPager);

    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, R.array.device_description);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.tabsSpinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    actionBarTabs = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBarTabs.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBarTabs.setCustomView(spinner);
    actionBarTabs.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBarTabs.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    tabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, viewPager); // Declares the tabs adapter class with the view pager view

    popupFirmware = new PopupFirmware(this); // Declaring popup firmware class

    /* Adds fragments to the tabs adapter */
    tabsAdapter.addTab(actionBarTabs.newTab().setText("PV"), Fragment_1.class, null);
    tabsAdapter.addTab(actionBarTabs.newTab().setText("CONFIG"), Fragment_2.class, null);
    tabsAdapter.addTab(actionBarTabs.newTab().setText("DIAG"), Fragment_3.class, null);

}
```

And here is the logcat:

```
11-20 13:16:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(11789): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-20 13:16:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(11789): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mobileapplicationretry/com.example.mobileapplicationretry.SlidingTabsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-20 13:16:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(11789):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
11-20 13:16:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(11789):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
11-20 13:16:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(11789):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-20 13:16:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(11789):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
11-20 13:16:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(11789):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-20 13:16:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(11789):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-20 13:16:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(11789):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-20 13:16:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(11789):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-20 13:16:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(11789):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-20 13:16:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(11789):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-20 13:16:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(11789):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-20 13:16:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(11789):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-20 13:16:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(11789): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-20 13:16:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(11789):    at com.example.mobileapplicationretry.SlidingTabsActivity.onCreate(SlidingTabsActivity.java:51)
11-20 13:16:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(11789):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
11-20 13:16:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(11789):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-20 13:16:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(11789):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
11-20 13:16:26.259: E/AndroidRuntime(11789):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: try getResources().getStringArray(R.array.device_description) intead only R.array.device_description in adapter.

Comment: I dont get why do you expect to find a spinner with id tabsSpinner inside the ViewPager

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your spinner is null.
Look, first you create `ViewPager` and making `setContentView`:

```
setContentView(viewPager);
```

but your `ViewPager` is empty cause you haven't put anything to it. And next you call:

```
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.tabsSpinner);
```

it means that `findViewById` will look for your spinner starting root view of your `Activity` - `ViewPager` you've create earlier, which is empty. So `Spinner` never will be found - and it is always null.

Comment: I see what you mean now. I want to add a spinner to my action bar and I am using an activity with 3 fragments as sliding tabs. How do I add the spinner to the action bar?

Comment: That will be another question :) Actually there are lot of examples on web and SO.

Comment: I have already asked that question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094971/is-it-possible-to-use-sliding-tabs-and-a-spinner-in-the-action-bar-in-android please help if you can

Answer (score 1):

To add `Spinner` in your `ActionBar` to control your `Viewpager`, you can do it like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {

ActionBar actionBar;
ViewPager mViewPager;
ArrayAdapter<String> mSpinnerAdapter;  

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewpager); // your layout Viewpager
 ...
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
 ...
    mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(actionBar.getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, R.array.device_description);
    actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter, this);
 }

 @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long id) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
    return false;
}

}
```

---

If you want to custom your Spinner, you can make two custom TextView, like follow:

Instead of:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> mSpinnerAdapter;  
mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(actionBar.getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, R.array.device_description);
```

Change to:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> mSpinnerAdapter;
// your custom TextView selected and your Spinner Array:
mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(actionBar.getThemedContext(), R.array.device_description, R.layout.spinner_selected_item);
// your custom TextView normal:
mSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you want both Navigation, I think you must to do a `Custom Tabbar` with `TextView`. Maybe you can try something like this (and keeping Spinner Navigation):

```
<!-- Tab Nav -->

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabnavmain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="0dip"
    android:stretchColumns="1" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tabrowmain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tabmain1"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="onNavSelected"
                android:clickable="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tabmain2"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="onNavSelected"
                android:clickable="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tabmain3"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="onNavSelected"
                android:clickable="true" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

<!-- End Tab Nav -->
```

And in your `Activity`, you can make a `NavListener`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // ...  
    NavListener navListener = new NavListener();  
}  

private class NavListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onNavSelected(View v) {
         switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.tabmain1:
                // do something like setCurrentItem(position) to your Viewpager
            break;
            case R.id.tabmain2:
                // do something else...
            break;
            case R.id.tabmain3:
                // do something...
            break;
         }
    }
};
```

You have to choose if you want `Tabs` OR `Spinner` navigation. I think you can't have both together.
Hope this help.

Comment: I know that you can't have both. But I just want a custom view of a spinner in the action bar and only have the tabs to navigate. The spinner will just update what is in the views in the fragments. Do you know how you can do this?

Comment: Yes, you have to force the Mode List Navigation, with this line: `setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);`.

Comment: I have done that and it takes away the tabs. I want to be able to keep the tabs and have a spinner in the action bar. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't really know about that, but maybe you can make a custom `Tabbar` to control your `Viewpager` plus your `Spinner`. See my update answer. It's not the best, but it's a clue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, R.array.device_description);
```

or

```
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, R.array.device_description);
```

It seems like your context is null