# Android Action Bar drop down menu width

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I want to handle the width of drop down menu on action bar. It is coming by default and title is not displayed in action bar.

In the google+ app width of drop down menu in action bar is very less. i want to have same in my app.
I am using App Compat library to use action bar.
Thanx.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11483149/1937802 try these

Comment: This is perfect solution and need some minor changes : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9118507/1802251